# Merge intervals in SQL - strange behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, intervals

I'm facing a strange issue with MySQL 5.5/5.6.
I've implemented a classic merge intervals algorithm in SQL, but it's not working as expected with some rows. I used [Merging intervals in one pass in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451925/merging-intervals-in-one-pass-in-sql) and [Most efficient way to sum overlapping datetimes in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924103/most-efficient-way-to-sum-overlapping-datetimes-in-mysql) as starting references (C++ @ http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/)

Anyone able to spot any issue on this?

```sql
SELECT MIN(inizio) as inizio, MAX(fine) as fine 
FROM (
    SELECT 
    @interval_id := IF(attendances.inizio > @interval_end, @interval_id + 1, @interval_id) AS interval_id, 
    @interval_end := IF(attendances.inizio < @interval_end, GREATEST(@interval_end, attendances.fine), attendances.fine) AS interval_end, 
    attendances.inizio, 
    attendances.fine 
    FROM attendances 
    INNER JOIN attendance_sheets ON ( attendance_sheet_id = attendance_sheets.id) 
    ORDER BY attendances.inizio,attendances.fine 
) intervals GROUP BY interval_id;
```

From these rows

[image]

I get a skipped @interval_id and wrong @interval_end for

[image]

which results in a wrong merge for 2017-01-26

[image]

thanks in advance
nicola

Comment: Probably need >= in your start date expression. Or <= in your end date.

Comment: Unfortunately I checked that as the first step, it's not related to <=/>=. What's more absurd, removing the 2017-01-28 10:00-12:30 everything works again. I've no words..